# Domain Not working

Tags: networking, web-server, domain, web-hosting, dns-zone

Domain was recently transferred to my hosting server. It has not worked since the transfer, I made sure all the DNS was up to date and even had the registry do a refresh and update them as well. I'm getting "Hmmm… can't reach this page". When I do a test is shows DNS server unavailable. I went to http://leafdns.com/ and it shows the SOA values was high so I changed them now it shows the retry is low. I also found out that the domain was on a blacklist. How can I fix all this and get the site back working. I contacted my Hosting Provider and they can see the website and saying everything is fine but no one else can see it. I need to get this fix so my customer can have her e-commerce up and running soon. I've tried so many things at this point I'm at a stand still. the domain is https://www.CiaraJane.com  if anyone can help me or point me to the right direction that be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen through [DNSViz](https://dnsviz.net/d/www.ciarajane.com/YanIQA/dnssec/), the domain previously used DNSSEC, and the parent zone still has the DNSSEC signing key defined, indicating to resolvers that they must reject unsigned data.

However, your new nameservers do not DNSSEC-sign the data (and even if they did, they'd be using a different key than the previous ones anyway), so resolvers of course reject the unsigned DNS responses as invalid.

You need to go to your domain registrar's control panel (the same place where you edit nameservers) and remove the DNSSEC keys or DS records for the domain.

The domain will start working as soon as visitors' DNS caches forget the old DS records – which might take a while, as the current records have a TTL of 2 days. (It's the same as changing nameservers.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked and i do not see DNSSEC OR DS records. I also contacted the registry to look further as well. They couldn't find anything either. What can I do to find this?

Comment: Did you follow https://launchpad.myorderbox.com/kb/node/1909 specifically? These records are not in _your_ zone; they are in the .com zone and are managed through a separate page.